# stripe payment firebase cloud function not updating database correctly

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, payment

I am using stripe payments in my app - trying to implement a user balance.

Currently, I have the following code in my index.js. The key bit for the question is the final `.then()` block of code. This section writes to my Cloud firestore database. However, it doesn't seem to actually update my database. When I look at my database, the balance doesn't change nor does the charge field get added to the stripe payment object that is saved in the database. I don't get any errors and I am not sure how to debug it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); //firebase functions library
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); //firebase admin database
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//initialse stripe with apikey
const stripe = require('stripe')('<stripe test key>')

//name of function is stripe charge
exports.stripeCharge = functions.database
    //whenever a new payment is written to the database, the following will be invoked
    .ref('/payments/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}')
    //event object has the data from the node in the database which is the payment and the token
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const payment = change.after.val();
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

        let balance = 0;

        //return null if there is no payment or if payment already has a charge
        if(!payment || payment.charge) return;

        //now we chain a promise - this is the user in the database
        //this is good for recurring charges or to save customer data in the database
        return admin.database()
            .ref(`/users/${userId}`)
            //once gives a single snapshot of this data
            .once('value')
            //return the snapshot value
            .then(snapshot => {
                return snapshop.val();
            })

            //tell stripe to charge the customer with the payment token
            .then(customer => {

                balance = customer.balance;

                const customerChargeAmount = payment.amount;
                const idempotency_key = paymentId; //prevents duplicate charges on customer cards
                const source = payment.token.id;
                const currency = 'gbp';
                const charge = {customerChargeAmount, currency, source};

                return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key});
            })

            //wait for stripe to return the actual stripe object which tells us whether the charge succeeded
            .then(charge => {

                if(!charge) return;

                let updates = {};
                updates[`/payments/${userId}/payments/${paymentId}/charge`] = charge

                if(charge.paid){
                    balance += charge.amount;
                    updates[`/users/${userId}/balance`] = balance;
                }

                admin.database().ref().update(updates);
                return true;
            })
    })
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your firebase functions log history and check if it has been executed at all. if not, make sure you make an update on your user payment node in the DB

Comment: Checked the logs, function is definitely being executed. How can I ensure an update is being made on the user payment node? One part of the index.js code also creates a stripe object and stores it in my DB. But, in the last .then block, nothing is being updated.